Using javascript for photoshop scripting, but I cant find the file
I am trying to make a script for photoshop in js, and I want to add an image to a new layer. The proble is that I simply cant find the jpg (teszt_fekvő.jpg), evendough it is in the same folder. Here is the code:
var newDoucument=app.documents.add(1080, 1080, 300, "New Document", NewDocumentMode.RGB);
var layers = newDoucument.artLayers;
var newLayer = layers.add();
newLayer.name = "New Layer";

var imagePath = new File("~/teszt_fekvő.jpg");

if(imagePath.exists) {
  placeFile(imagePath);
} else {
  alert("File not found");
}

I have tried absolute filepath, and I am 100% that the name of the file is correct.

Note that you're assigning imagePath = new File(...) and then you immediate throw that away and overwrite the variable by using imagePath = File.openDialog(...).

thanks for the comment left it there accidentally

File is a thin wrapper around the OS's file handling without its own logic, so which OS are you running? Because if it's Windows, ~ is not part of a valid path (so your script will silently error out), and if it's MacOS, ~ is your home directory. One thing you probably want to do is make liberal use of try { ... } catch (e) { alert(...) } to catch errors. Photoshop scripting is basically an exercise in "do I remember all the best practices from 1998" because of how old the version of JS involved is =)

Thanks for the help it solved the issue. The funny thing is, that if the JS is really that old, that means I wasnt even born yet

It's ActionScript 3, based on JavaScript 1.5. So yeah, it really is that old.
